# About Android's PNG vulnerability

Tags: android, vulnerability

I'm curious about this vulnerability. I know that can execute code remotely and needs user interaction, but what type of interaction? Download the image? Copy it? I will appreciate if someone can answer me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file can be specifically crafted to trigger the malicious code when the user opens it (views it) on his device (local or via a received link).

The vulnerability associated with the PNG bug can be tracked as CVE-2019-1986, CVE-2019-1987, CVE-2019-1988.

CVE-2019-1986 – Uninitialized errors in SkPngCodec

CVE-2019-1987 – Heap buffer overflow

CVE-2019-1988 – Bug decoding JCS_RGB jpeg files

Comment: So, just view the image (by email or in a web site) trigger the infection?

Comment: Yes. That is why it was considered highly dangerous.

Comment: Is update android or buy a new phone the only solutions?

Comment: Officially, it is recommended to update, since the vulnerability was patched.

Comment: The problem is manufacturers delays to provide such updates

Comment: Generally true, but this one is patched. But be warned that only android 7 & 9 receive security updates.

Comment: According to CVEs, it's because only these versions has the vulnerability.